# GPU Rendering causing strange lines

Tags: rendering, gpu

When I render using my r9 390 graphics card, weird lines are appearing over the render. This problem has just started happening recently, as a few days ago I was rendering the same scene without the lines appearing. I don't believe I've changed any settings in Blender and the below scene is from a new file, so render settings should be default.
[image: GPU render]

Rendering using my CPU is fine:
[image: CPU render]

The only thing I can think that has changed is I recently updated my card to the latest drivers. Playing games with it is still fine and the card is quite new so I wouldn't think it's a problem with the card itself.

Comment: please report the bug: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/T48028

Answer (score 3):

Further googling found that it is a driver issue:
https://community.amd.com/thread/198677