# Ugly stripes when rendering with GPU, even with high samples

Tags: gpu, opencl

I came across a problem which I couldn't find any solution through google.
With my new GPU (R9 390X) I get when rendering with it, distinct stripes, especially in darker areas.
Does anyone know the reason for this?

Thanks a lot!

[image: GPU vs. CPU rendering]

Comment: I uploaded the .blend file here: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1182" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1182/)

Comment: I guess you activated OpenCL which is an experimental 'config'. Like discussted in this Maniphest for blender-problems https://developer.blender.org/T30886 there is not much that can be done now.

Comment: Are you using an AMD card? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50095/gpu-rendering-causing-strange-lines

Comment: Yes It´s a Radeon R390X. It looks like AMD screwed up the driver.  ... OpenCL rendering is broken with latest Crimson drivers (16.4.1) ...